# Unable to properly define MongoDB connection string as an Travis CI environmental variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, travis-ci

I'm working on my own project using Node.js and MongoDB as a database (using Mongoose).

When I developed it locally, I defined my environmental variables in a .env file and used 'env-cmd'.

Now I'm trying to create a testing workflow using Travis-CI without using a .env file so I defined my environmental variables on the repository setting but I keep getting an error that the connection string is invalid when trying to build:

[image]

It is worth mentioning that:

- I escaped every special character when defining the env variable of the connection string.
- I tried passing both process.env.MONGODB_URL with and without the ES6 backticks format to the mongoose.connect() method.
- The connection string is valid (I tried running my test suites locally with the .env file and it worked)
- The connection string is to the MongoDB Atlas database, not a local one.
- I'm running the tests from as a docker container.

I can't figure out what is the problem, and if any additional information is needed to tackle this problem I will happily provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to run a debug session and verify that the environment variable is correctly set in the travis runner?

Comment: I got it working eventually. The issue was that I didn't define the environmental variables inside the container, only outside.